# Splash Page with progress bar in qml for blackberry 10

Tags: progress-bar, qml, splash-screen, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm developing an application for blackberry 10 with native sdk.

I want to show a splash page/screen with some progress bar whenever the application launches i.e when the user clicks on the application icon.

First I want to create sqlite database and some tables after that get the data from server and store the data in sqlite database tables. After this work done, I've to remove this splash page and then i've to show the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the splashscreen itself, you'll not be able to use the BlackBerry splashscreen functionality, as it's just displaying a static picture. So you'll have to create a simple `Sheet` to do this: set an image as static splashscreen, and create a `Sheet` with the same image in background. On top of the image, display a `ProgressBar` or something like that. When your initialization is complete, close the `Sheet`.

The progress computation will be split in two parts: first, getting your content. You'll have to use the [`QNetworkReply::downloadProgress`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#downloadProgress) signal to monitor the download. Then you'll have to add some hard-coded "progress" for the database creation/filling. Depending on your data quantity, I'll split it in 90% download, 10% database filling.

Comment: Could you please provide me the code how to create sheet and add progress bar.